# Скачивание файла

Tags: windows, c++

Каким образом можно скачать файл с сайта? Какие функции нужно использовать?

P. S.: Спасибо за за подсказку с WinInet. Вот ещё одна статья по теме: «[WinInet: скачка\докачка файлов по http-протоколу](http://netcode.ru/cpp/?lang=&katID=19&skatID=173&artID=5099)»<sup>[[архив](https://web.archive.org/web/20160826083501/http://netcode.ru/cpp/?lang=&katID=19&skatID=173&artID=5099)]</sup>.

Comment: Сокеты + протоколы http или ftp

Comment: Пару готовых примеров на разных библиотеках с подробными объяснениями можно найти в статье «[Введение в WinInet](https://web.archive.org/web/20150517002714/http://rsdn.ru/article/inet/wininet.xml)» на RSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого подойдет библиотека [Urdl](http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/index.html) или [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/). Кроме того можно посмотреть исходники [wget](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/wget/trunk/files) и переиспользовать их.